# Hibernate : Third level caching

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

Is it possible to create a third level cache in Hibernate ? Definitely a customized one but will it be feasible to have one ?

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking to setup your own custom cache that has nothing to do with Hibernate directly. A third level cache in Hibernate seems pointless.

Comment: I definitely understand that it is not having any major impact as far as Hibernate functionality is concerned but if there was a third level cache , how would it be useful overall towards the performance of queries or fetching data from the DB. I am just puzzled around that or may be trying to find a more optimized solution.

Comment: You don't even explain what you expect from a third level cache, if it is performance then that is basically what the first and second level caches are already for. What does a second level cache not do that you expect to solve with a third level cache?